# Need help to solve a double integral with absolute value.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Need help to solve this double integral:

$$\int_0^1  \int_0^1  \lvert x-y\rvert \,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$$

I was thinking that because of its absolute value I could divide it into two cases, one case with positive and another case with negative, and then integrate each case. However, both cases give me the answer zero.

Comment: Case $1$: $1\ge x\ge y\ge0\implies I_1=\int_0^1\int_0^x(x-y)~dy~dx=\frac16$. Can you evaluate case $2$ when $0\le x<y\le1$? If you are still getting zero post your calculation for us to review.

Comment: In fact if you write the second integral in $dx \ dy$ order, you can show it is same as the first integral

Comment: Try to visualize the integrand. The geometry isn't bad and it is helpful to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the interchange $x\leftrightarrow y$, the integral stays the same, so we can say by symmetry

$$I = 2\int_0^1 \int_0^x x-y\:dydx = \int_0^1 x^2\:dx = \frac{1}{3}$$